How to View Local DB created using Expo Sqlite
I have created a local DB that is stored in my iOS device using Expo SqLite and I am having great difficulty accessing the table content to view the data stored.
I have tried the following:

I installed the File System Package npx expo install expo-file-system

Then I wanted to see what FileSystem.documentDirectory will log out, because I didn't know where expo keeps my stuff.
So I simply created a button and onClick I logged the value it returns


FileSystemPath = async () => {
    console.log(FileSystem.documentDirectory)   
}

This is what is logged: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6357EEE7-87AB-437F-81DD-5D4251DB2D90/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/@anonymous/NewLocation-e77cbc5e-75f8-495d-b98f-08cd529311f4/';
I then used the below code to navigate to the directory in my iOS device:
const directoryPath =
    "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6357EEE7-87AB-437F-81DD-5D4251DB2D90/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/@anonymous/NewLocation-e77cbc5e-75f8-495d-b98f-08cd529311f4/";

  async function shareSQLiteFile() {
    try {
      const files = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(directoryPath);
      if (files.length > 0) {
        const filePath = `${directoryPath}/${files[0]}`; // Assuming you want to share the first file
        await Sharing.shareAsync(filePath);
        console.log("File shared:", filePath);
      } else {
        console.log("No files in directory");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sharing file:", error);
    }
  }

This has allowed me to share the SQLite file on my iOS device and have it saved on the device, but now my issue is that I can't open the file and there are no suitable file readers available for the document, any advice on how to proceed?
